# I want to write and read a list of a text file in python

Tags: python

I found a solutuion for writing my list in a txt file with this code:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    string1 = "".join(map(str, LIST))
    f.write(string1)
```

the list looks something like this:
[[(227, 489), 10, (255, 255, 255)][(227, 489), 10, (255, 255, 255)][(227, 489), 10, (255, 255, 255)]]

but if i want to read the list with this code:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    circles = [f.read()]
    print(circles)
```

everything is in "" and the error is: IndexError: string index out of range

here is the whole code of the program:

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

pen_color = (255, 255, 255)
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 1000
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# COLORS
GREEN_IMG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Colors", "green.png"))
GREEN = pygame.transform.scale(GREEN_IMG, (50, 50))
pen_size = 10

circles = []

def draw_colors():
    global pen_color
    WIN.blit(GREEN, (900, 900))
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mouse_pressed[0]:
        if 900 <= mouse[0] <= 950 and 900 <= mouse[1] <= 950:
            pen_color = (0, 255, 0)

def handle_drawing():
    mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mouse_pressed[0]:
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        circles.append([mouse_pos, pen_size, pen_color])
    for circle in circles:
        print(circles)
        pygame.draw.circle(WIN, circle[2], (circle[0][0], circle[0][1]), circle[1])
        print(pen_color)
    

def key_control():
    global pen_size
    global circles
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_b]:
        pen_size += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
            string1 = "".join(map(str,circles))
            f.write(string1)
    if keys[pygame.K_o]:
        with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
            circles = [f.read()]
            print(circles)

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                break
        key_control()
        handle_drawing()
        draw_colors()
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest considering usage of [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) built-in module. You can use it following way for writing

```
import pickle
data = [1,(2,3)]
with open('save.p','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

and following way for reading

```
import pickle
with open('save.p','rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
print(data)  # [1, (2, 3)]
```

Beware that `pickle` is not secure (read linked docs for more information). `pickle` is one of way of providing *persistent storage* if it doesn not suit your needs you might try searching for another method - look for *persistent storage python*

Answer (score 1):

As pickle is not secure you can use `json` format

```
dump/dumps: Serialize
load/loads: Deserialize
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Code:

```
>>> import json
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> with open("test.txt", "w") as fp:
...     json.dump(l, fp)
...
>>> with open("test.txt", "r") as fp:
...     b = json.load(fp)
...
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to write a python list to a txt file and then read it back in as a list you need to do something like this.

Write it with some delimiter.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
    string1 = ",".join(map(str, LIST))
    f.write(string1)
```

And then read it in and split it on that same delimiter.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
    my_list = text.split(',')
```